# eevee holdout white outline

Tags: rendering

I rendered two images with holdout mask but when I was to assemble them in photoshop I notice there was a white outline around the masked out object (in my case the trees). If I put a background under each of them I could see there was no white outline. So I figured out it's because Blender somehow rendered the masked out area bigger than it should be. So after I put the trees on top of the grass I could see a white outline which was not actually white outline but transparent outline. How could I solve this problem?
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a Blender problem as such, but a problem with how you are combining the images. At the boundary you will be combining two part-transparent pixels, but expecting a non-transparent result (otherwise the default white background shows through). Consider the images as being on two transparent sheets of glass and you can see that you could result will light passing through both panes rather than blocking all light as you are expecting.

In your particular case, you can probably get away with just using 'black' as the base colour - to prevent any additional light shining through any residual transparency at the boundary.

Comment: I understand transparent pixels+transparent pixels = transparent pixels. But Isn't the problem rendered one of them 1 pixel smaller? If they are rendered precisely then there won't be overlapping transparent pixles?

Comment: Hi Ken. By default the rendering uses anti-aliasing and so multiple samples are taken around each pixel. This means the pixels on the boundary could be part transparent - and their counterpart on the other image also part transparent, triggering the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much, now I understand what you mean. But is there anyway I can turn off the anti-aliasing in the blender rendering? Also, I noticed that if I use a compositor in blender, the problem is gone. The reason why I need to holdout them is I need to render the trees and grass with Eevee but there is one juice stand which I didn’t put here I need to render in Cycles so I get more realistic lighting effect. So I need to render them separately and assemble together.

Comment: You look like an expert XD. Please also check this question https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/297290/how-is-this-grass-made

Comment: I guess you could set the number of samples to '1' and make sure you use the same 'Seed' in the 'Advanced' Cycles settings for each render, but you'll lose a lot of quality. Better to combine the images properly, taking into account the transparency for both layers - eg, by removing any transparency from the first image first.