# How is this grass made?

Tags: modeling, rendering

There is grass is very mysteriously made to me. In edit mode you can see it's made of multiple planes. But in object mode it becomes much bigger as if there was a array modifier added on. But there is no any modifiers or physicals. How is this made?
[image]

[image]

Update: I included the file here  [grass.blend](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WLV3o1pNXf_89KtxikLSi9gSs36-pFe4/view?usp=sharing)

Please check it with viewport render preview. Also I wonder how this data tansfer modifer work? Why if I disable the datatransfer modifer the color of the grass will look off. I understand it as it transfers the normal from the ground? But why it makes a difference?

[image]

Comment: Hello, hard to say without the file, maybe geonodes, or instancing?

Comment: I have added an answer, but if you need steps to recreate just reply to this comment in that case. I will edit and update the answer then.

Comment: @Akshay2005 it looks like his question is rather how the plane is repeated

Comment: @moonboots I have added the changes. I assumed that he imported the model from somewhere. But you are right, the file will help.

Comment: Geometry nodes would show as a modifier. What about these two vertex groups in the outliner? How are they assigned?

Comment: @moonboots There is no geonode since it’s also a modifier. I don’t know how instancing can scatter them around.

Comment: The Scatter Objects addon will create some triangles, but hard to say without the file, please share it: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @moonboots Please check in the discription. I updated the file.

Answer (score 1):

No modifier here, your meshes are just hidden, in *Edit* mode, press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>

Comment: OMG...I'm an idiot ..I was confused by this for a very long time!! Thank you! Can you answer my question about the rendering and the normal tansfer? Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure what the Face Corner Data is doing in the Data Transfer modifier, I hope someone will tell